# IOS Shortcuts: Setting (nested) dictionaries with application to modify EXIF data

Tags: ios, dictionary

I am trying to set values in a nested dictionary - similar to pythonic `dict["key1"]["key2"]=value1` in Apple's my shortcut app on IOS 13. I fail even with a simple dict see attached screenshot which should add an element to the dict. The endgame is to modify EXIF metadata via the Metapho app - [non-working example attached](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/6b17e3b301bf4cb7a31bb1be6e9d66e8)

I  used ttwo approached

1. use a basic operation to modify dictionary
2. use prexisting shortcuts to modify dicitonaries as outline on the following Reddit threat [Dictionary utilites](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9yxq9s/dictionary_utilities/).

To reproduce you need to download the attached shortcuts - and Dictionary utilties for the examples using those.

I first checked if I can modify a non-nested dict and nonnested dict.

## Modifying non-nested dictionary

Using core tools I cannot add a key-value pair to a dictionary.
[Minmal non-working exampleas per below](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/9ed90912077143bcbbd46714e02129c1).

[image]

[image]

## Modifying non-nested dictionary using Dictionary tools

[Minmal working example](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/4598f1589cc344ed933ed7afc117ad9b)

## Modifying nested dictionary using Dictionary tools

Using the same tools to modify nested dicts does not work.
[Minimal non working example](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/08f4e04ff11e49c78a90908e9596e9e2)

Any help greatly appreciated. [Asked same question on ask different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395943/ios-shortcuts-setting-nested-dictionaries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values of a  dictionary are modified the variable needs to be reset:

[reset variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GargJ.jpg)

Using this both nested and non-nested dicts can be modified without external tools.
Essentially this is called by value instead of call by reference. If those tools are used still their output needs to overwrite the variable in question.

Regarding modifying the underlying Exif values it is important it is important that again the output imagevariable needs to be written to new file in the photo app.

Mac